# Python, строка из 0 и 1 в ascii

Tags: python, строки, ascii

Всем привет.
Есть строка - '01101000', в ascii это буква h. Необходимо сделать перевод этих символов, собственно, в ascii и на выходе получить h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В число преобразовать, затем в символ:

```
  print(chr(int('01101000',2)))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое :)